# Finding the transformation matrix that belongs to the linear map

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, 3d, coordinate-systems, transformation

I am given a linear map with:
$$
\begin{align}
f(1,1,0) &= (3,7,1) \\
f(1,0,1) &= (3,4,2) \\
f(0,2,1) &= (-1,2,1)
\end{align}
$$

and I have to find a $3 \times 3$ matrix that belongs to this linear map.

The one I found is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -1 &  -1 \\
6 & -1 & -12 \\
1 &  0 &   0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and I got this by subtracting and adding the other $f$'s from one another and then applying the same formula to the other vectors, to basically get:
$f(0,0,1)$, $f(0,1,0)$, $f(1,0,0)$

..but I'm not sure if what I got is right or if I even used the correct method.
Every help is greatly appreciated, I'm really having some trouble here.

Edit:

Okay I have found out a method to verify my result and I found out that what I calculated is completely wrong. Right now I'm trying to figure out how to actually do it.

Comment: Your method should be fine, and you can verify your result by multiplying the matrix by the column vectors $(1,1,0)^T,\ (1,0,1)^T,\ (0,2,1)^T$.

Comment: Nahh I messed up, I'm trying to do it with that method but it doesn't quite work because of all the 0s

Comment: i think i almost got it im gonna fiddle around a bit longer

Comment: Do you know how to calculate the inverse of a matrix? Basically that's what you're doing: finding the inverse of $\pmatrix{1&1&0\\1&0&2\\0&1&1}$.

Comment: But when I do that, I get 0 for each of the results when I verify them?

Comment: wait nevermind... one sec

Comment: I thought I would have to multiply the inversed matrix with the vectors I'm trying to get but that didn't seem to work either. I feel like this is really easy but I just can't figure out the right way to do it...

Comment: im going insane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's denote the implicitly given basis vectors by $a=(1,1,0)^T,\ ,b=(1,0,1)^T,\ c=(0,2,1)^T$.

Then we have $a-b=(0,1,-1)^T$, $c-2(a-b)=(0,0,3)^T$, thus we can express $e_3=(0,0,1)$ and therefore also $e_1=b-e_3$ and $e_2=a-e_1$.

Note that arranging the resulting coefficients of $a,b,c$ in columns we obtain the *inverse* of the matrix $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: I seem to still misunderstand something. I tried applying this and I got:

-1,-4,3 |

-1,-1,0 |

4,8,-1

which leads me when verifying to correct results for a and c but not for b..

Comment: ohh nevermind i think i just forgot dividing by 3 at the end there

Comment: nevermind i think im just making it worse..

Comment: OH SH** I THINK I ALMOST GOT IT HOLD ON

Comment: YES I GOT IT THANK YOU I WAS ON THIS THE ENTIRE DAY I ALMOST WENT INSANE THANK YOU SO MUCH AHHHH